# Short story about person being replaced/rebuilt by tiny creatures

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a story in 7th grade, around 1983-84, where somehow in it a man realizes that he is slowly being replaced from the inside by tiny bugs/aliens/robots that work together as a unit.

He tries to struggle against it/them but winds up losing the fight and disappearing even though it looks like he is still there to others (it's actually the tiny Invaders).

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.

Comment: Possibly blood music? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_Music_(novel)

Comment: I recall reading this earlier, around early 1970s.  The little creatures were called "nergs" when the replacement called them home, resulting in disassembly of the victim/protagonist.  Can't find anything with a search on "nergs", though.

Comment: Maybe something in the first *Dangerous Visions*?  I read that collection about that time...

Comment: Well, I found a list of the contents, and it doesn't seem to be either *Dangerous Visions* or *Again, Dangerous Visions*, but I'm pretty sure I saw it in a collection in the early 1970s.